# how can access existing contact number in my application

Tags: iphone

Hai
     how can we access existing contact number in our application?
 Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Add Addressbook frame work in your app.

Then add ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate in .h file

in .m file

then on add button perform this code`and following address book delegates

```
-(void)ClkAddContactBtn:(id)sender
```

{
    // creating the picker
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    // place the delegate of the picker to the controll
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

```
// showing the picker
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
// releasing
[picker release];
```

}

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
```

{
    // assigning control back to the main controller
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
```

{

```
NSString *firstName=[[NSString alloc]init];
firstName=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

NSString *lastName=[[NSString alloc]init];
lastName=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

if (lastName == nil)
{
    lastName=@" ";   

    NSString *fullName=[[NSString alloc]init];
    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@", firstName, lastName];


    txtContactName.text = fullName;

    ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    txtContactNo.text = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);


    // remove the controller
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
else if(firstName == nil)
{
    firstName=@" ";  

    NSString *fullName=[[NSString alloc]init];
    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@", firstName, lastName];


    txtContactName.text = fullName;

    ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    txtContactNo.text = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);


    // remove the controller
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
else 
{

    NSString *fullName=[[NSString alloc]init];
    fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@", firstName, lastName];


    txtContactName.text = fullName;

    ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    txtContactNo.text = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);


    // remove the controller
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


return NO;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
```

{
    return NO;
}

`

Answer (score 1):

Check the ABAddressBook Reference

[ABAdressBook Class Refernce](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html)